# using for loop how to increment any number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Write a program containing a loop that iterates from 1 to 1000 using a variable `I`, which is incremented each time around the loop. The program should output the value of `I` every hundred iterations (i.e., the output should be 100, 200, etc).  Display the output on the screen using `dbms_output.put_line`.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far!

Comment: -1 for posting homework without (apparently) having made any attempt to complete the assignment yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
FOR I IN 1..1000
LOOP
   IF MOD(I, 100) = 0 THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
   END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Reference:

- [FOR loop](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/for_loop.php)
- [IF statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php)
- [MOD](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php)

Answer (score 2):

This might be faster:

```
begin
 dbms_output.put_line('100');
 dbms_output.put_line('200');
 dbms_output.put_line('300');
 dbms_output.put_line('400');
 dbms_output.put_line('500');
 dbms_output.put_line('600');
 dbms_output.put_line('700');
 dbms_output.put_line('800');
 dbms_output.put_line('900');
 dbms_output.put_line('1000');
end;
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could implement this as

```
FOR I IN 1..1000 LOOP
  IF I IN (100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

or

```
FOR I IN 1..1000 LOOP
  IF I/100 = TRUNC(I/100) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

or even

```
DECLARE
  INPUT_NUM   NUMBER;
  OUTPUT_NUM  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN 1..1000 LOOP
    SELECT I/100, TRUNC(I/100)
      INTO INPUT_NUM, OUTPUT_NUM
      FROM DUAL;

    IF INPUT_NUM = OUTPUT_NUM THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(I);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.